# onchange isn't working

Tags: javascript, events, onchange

I am learning JavaScript through the Head First series book by O'Reilly media, and I just reached a chapter where I have to use the `onchange` event.

I'm testing using Safari/OS X Lion, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and IE/Windows, but got the same result.

Given this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>onChange Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function itWorks(){
                alert("it works!");   
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" onchange="itWorks();" />
            <input type="text" onchange="itWorks();" />
        </form>
    </body>
<html>
```

Is it correct to say that the `onchange` event works whenever we change from one field to another, whether it is activated only by clicking or by using the TAB key?

Comment: It works whenever the value of field is changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The onchange event fires when:

- Focus leaves the field
- **if** the value has changed since focus was gained

It doesn't matter how focus was lost, and focus doesn't need to move to another field (a link could be focused, or nothing in the document could be, etc).

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something silly, but it just never came across my mind to try that. Anyways, it worked. Oh, and I'll try to ask more objective questions from now on. (:

Answer (score 1):

> "we change from one field to another, whether its by clicking or by
>   using the TAB key"  -

Thats onblur.

the event you have coded fires whenever you change the value of the input, then leave the field. EG: Enter something into the field, then press the TAB key.

Your example code works as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviors you described is onfocus. onchange executes when the value of the input changes. 
If you type something into the field, it should run.

Answer (score 0):

> "Just to clarify, the onchange event works whenever we change from one field to another, whether its by clicking or by using the TAB key, right?"

Yes - as long as the value has changed

I'm not sure what the question is tbh - your code works!
I [tested it](http://jsfiddle.net/zqw6U/) on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) - which is great for learing / testing javascript.

(you should close your html tag btw)...

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [HTML5 draft spec says](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/editing.html#unfocusing-steps):

> The unfocusing steps are as follows:
>
> **If the element is an input element, and the change event applies
> to the element, and the element does not have a defined activation
> behavior, and the user has changed the element's value or its list of
> selected files while the control was focused without committing that
> change, then fire a simple event that bubbles named *change* at the
> element.**
>
> Unfocus the element.
>
> Fire a simple event named blur at the element.

Note that *change* can fire at other times too. [The spec also says](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-input-element-attributes.html#event-input-change):

> ... any time the user commits a change to the element's value or list of
> selected files, the user agent must queue a task to fire a simple
> event that bubbles named *change* at the input element.

And goes on to provide a couple of examples of "committing a change"

> An example of a user interface with a commit action would be a File
> Upload control that consists of a single button that brings up a file
> selection dialog: when the dialog is closed, if that the file
> selection changed as a result, then the user has committed a new file
> selection.
>
> Another example of a user interface with a commit action would be a
> Date control that allows both text-based user input and user selection
> from a drop-down calendar: while text input might not have an explicit
> commit step, selecting a date from the drop down calendar and then
> dismissing the drop down would be a commit action.